# React Native SQLite: Cannot convert null value to object, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite

I'm trying to add the react-native-sqlite-storage module to my project. But somehow it doesn't work as it does not want to open the database.

```js
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
import { WorkoutDataContext, WorkoutDataSetterContext } from '../App';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: "test.db"});


export const saveWorkout = () => {
 ...
```

Line 5 errors with: TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object, js engine: hermes

But I dont understand why. I even have the module installed correctly...